# Rename-Item error: Cannot rename because item does not exist

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following powershell code, which is attempting to rename all SQL files in a folder, adding a unique prefix to each file e.g. the first prefix will be '1001 - sp - C - ':

```
gci -Path 'C:\FolderToLookIn' -Exclude "1*" | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        'LineNumber' = $linenumber;
        'Name'       = $_.Name;
        'Extension'  = $_.Extension
    };
    $linenumber++
} | Where-Object {
    $_.Extension -eq ".sql"
} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.LineNumber.ToString("1000") + ' - sp - C - ' + $_.Name}
```

However, this produces errors such as the following:

> Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at '@{Extension=.sql; LineNumber=22; Name=sp_Firm_GetAll.sql}' does not exist.

So, how can I add the `LineNumber` property and use it as a prefix in the `Rename-Item` command without losing the item itself?

---

**Edit**

I have also tried the following, passing through the `FullName` and using this in the `Rename-Item`:

```
gci -Path 'C:\FolderToSearch' -Exclude "1*" | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object psObject -Property @{
        'LineNumber' = $linenumber;
        'Name'       = $_.Name;
        'Extension'  = $_.Extension;
        'FullName'   = $_.FullName
    };
    $linenumber++
} | Where-Object {
    $_.Extension -eq ".sql"
} | Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName {$_.LineNumber.ToString("1000") + ' - sp - C - ' + $_.Name}
```

However, this errors also:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:3 char:19
+ Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName {$_.LineNumber.ToString("1000") + ' - sp
```

Comment: `Rename-Item` doesn't have a `FullName` parameter - in your last example, change `'FullName'= $_.FullName` -> `'LiteralPath'= $_.FullName` instead

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, I tried changing property name in the new object from FullName to LiteralPath and updating `$_.FullName` to `$_.LiteralPath` in the `rename-item` section, however this still returns the error "Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null."

Comment: No. Remove the `-Path` parameter and its argument from that statement entirely as you're reading the input from a pipeline.

Comment: Why don't you restrict the gci to `*.sql` files first place instead of using a `Where-Object`? While you exclude `1*`, on successive runs the same prefix `1000 - sp - C - ` would be generated (as the old names were unique)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sorry I'm not quite there still! I have tried this now without the Path as it was in my first try and without the Path but with FullName changed to LiteralPath as Mathias suggested but the errors returned are similar to the first errors I was receiving. If anyone has a working example they could post as an answer to this that would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @LotPings thanks, I have applied your suggestion regarding the file extenstions to avoid the unnecessary `Where-Object` code. Are you saying if this was run twice then the prefixes for any additional files would be the same as the ones created the first time it was executed? If that's the case thanks for pointing it out, I will look at that when I get the code working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As

- Rename-Item accepts piped input the `ForEach` isn't necessary and
- with a `[Ref]` you can increment a counter inside the `-NewName {scriptblock}`

---

```
$Folder = 'C:\FolderToLookIn'

$Count = [ref] 0
Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.sql -File |
  Where-Object Name -NotMatch '^\d{4} - sp - C - ' | 
    Rename-Item -Newname {"{0:1000} - sp - C - {1}" -f $Count.Value++,$_.Name}
```

A sample folder with A.sql, B.sql, C.sql will have this result:

```
> gci *.sql -name
1000 - sp - C - A.sql
1001 - sp - C - B.sql
1002 - sp - C - C.sql
```

A variant which first obtains the last/highest number from existing files or sets 1000 as the start.

```
$Count = [Ref][math]::Max(1000,
    [int](Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.sql -File|
            Where-Object Name -match '^(\d{4}) - sp - C -' | 
            Select-Object @{n='Count';e={$Matches[1]}} -Last 1).Count)

Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.sql -File |
  Where-Object Name -NotMatch '^\d{4} - sp - C - ' | 
    Rename-item -Newname {"{0:D4} - sp - C - {1}" -f ++$Count.Value,$_.Name}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and a lot neater solution, thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks @LotPings, this is very useful. Please see my follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55298409/2242458) as I am struggling to understand some of the code used.