# Powershell number notation matches and rename-item logic

Tags: powershell, match, powershell-3.0

In the below solution for renaming files taken from an answer to my question [Rename-Item error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55280636/2242458), what do the following bits of code do?

1. `^\d{4}`
2. `e={$Matches[1]}`
3. `Rename-item -Newname {"{0:D4} - sp - C - {1}" -f ++$Count.Value,$_.Name}`

For 1. I think this is saying a four digit number but I would like to understand the notation used.

For 2. `$Matches` hasn't been set anywhere, is this a variable specific to `Select-Object`?

For 3. what is `{0:D4}` doing and the `{1}` at the end of the same string. Also, is this line concatenating two strings with the comma delimiter?

```
$Count = [Ref][math]::Max(1000,
    [int](Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.sql -File|
            Where-Object Name -match '^(\d{4}) - sp - C -' | 
            Select-Object @{n='Count';e={$Matches[1]}} -Last 1).Count)

Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.sql -File |
  Where-Object Name -NotMatch '^\d{4} - sp - C - ' | 
    Rename-item -Newname {"{0:D4} - sp - C - {1}" -f ++$Count.Value,$_.Name}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `^\d{4}` is a [Regular Expression](https://regular-expressions.info)
   `^` anchors at line begin
   `\d` represents a digit
   `{4}` is a quantifier, specifying exactly 4 of the previous, here digits
   `()` parentheses mark a capture group
2. cite from `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`

   > The `-Match` and `-NotMatch` operators populate the `$Matches` automatic variable.

   Where `$Matches[1]` represents the 1st capture group of the RegEx.
   The `Select-Object` builds a calculated property from the match (4 digit number) and only uses the last/highest
3. Obtaining the previously used highest number was a bonus I should have explained better 1st place.
   As the obtained number now contains 4 digits (no more a fixed 1 and three zeroes) the `-format` [operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) (shorted to just `-f`) is used to build the new file name by inserting variable contents in place of the `{x}` where x is a zero based number.